# Django prevent multiple submits

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using Django 1.9

I am trying to create a protection of the user clicking multiple times on the submit button.

What I did I create a unique token for the form; when you submit the form a decorator checks do you have session var with the same token. In theory should work in practise no. If I click 10 times will get around 5-6 new entries

Here is the code

My View:

```
   @form_token_check
   def new(request, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST" and kwargs['form_token']:
        ====write to DB=====
```

My decorator:

```
def form_token_check(func):
  def inner(request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['form_token'] = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        new_form_token = request.POST.get('form-token', '')

        if 'form-token' in request.session:
            old_form_token = request.session['form-token']

            if new_form_token != old_form_token:
                kwargs['form_token'] = True
                request.session['form-token'] = new_form_token
        else:
            kwargs['form_token'] = True
            request.session['mlvr-form-token'] = new_form_token

    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

return inner
```

Answer (score 0):

From my opinion, It is good to do prevent in client side (javascript, jquery, etc.).Because, in your approach user can still send multiple submits since session variable is setting in server side only until client got response(client is not waiting for response).

Comment: I would like to have server side protection